# SOLVED - ]Read data and copy to current workbook

Tags: excel, vba

With below code, no errors are displayed, the read file opens but it seems not data is copied.
I am trying to copy only a number of columns, but it seems nothing is been copied to current workbook.

Any help would be appreciated as I am very new with VBA

```
    Sub ReadDataFromCloseFile()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    'stop screen update
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim src As Workbook
    Dim sTheSourceFile As String
    sTheSourceFile = "C:\Users\grmn\Desktop\testreadfile.xlsx"
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(sTheSourceFile, True, True)
    
    
    Dim iRowsCount As Long
    'source of data
    With src.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        iRowsCount = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count
    End With
    
    Dim iCnt As Long
    'destination sheet thisWorkbook.sheet("rapport")
 
    For iCnt = 1 To iRowsCount
        Worksheets("rapport").Range("A" & iCnt).Formula = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iCnt).Formula
        Worksheets("rapport").Range("F" & iCnt).Formula = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & iCnt).Formula
    Next iCnt
    
    'close but not overide source file (src).
    src.Close False
    Set src = Nothing
    
ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `iRowsCount` will only ever be the rows in column AT, so why set it so many times?  You're also defining based on `src.Worksheets("Sheet")` but copying from `src.Worksheets("Sheet1").` and putting them all in column A.  The `Rows.Count` also doesn't reference your with statement.  You also can just use the `.Row` of the end row, no need for the the range.rows.count.

Comment: typo sheet 2 sheet1 fixed, not completely following what you mean by not needing to set iRowsCount that many times. as Said newbie in vba

Comment: The value of `iRowsCount` is being overwritten every single time so only the last one counts, which is column AT so the question - Why assign it so many times when the variable is only going to hold the last assignment?

Comment: If an error occurs your code jumps to the end of the procedure.  Comment out the `On Error Goto...` line and see if any errors occur.  The error handlers should also be outside the main procedure - after an `Exit Sub` and before the `End Sub`.

Comment: I believed it was looking up the total number of rows, number of rows of all columns are the same. (total # of rows to copy). Removed the un necesary ones.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook , commented out on error go : which gave me "Worksheets("rapport").Range("A" & iCnt).Formula = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iCnt).Formula" subscript out of range error

Comment: Which Workbook is `rapport` Worksheet located? The current Workbook (which you run the code from)? I suggest you fully qualify your range for `Worksheets("rapport")`. @Grmn

Comment: Active workbook to read / copy data to ~Documents (sheet = rapport), testfile to read the data from in ~Desktop (sheet = sheet1) @RaymondWu

Comment: Don't rely on ActiveWorkbook or ActiveSheet. The `Workbooks.Open` will change the ActiveWorkbook. If your dest worksheet is in the workbook where the code lives, you can use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rapport")` (as you already mention in the comment of your code), or assign it to a worksheet variable (similar to  `src`). But you should never use an unqualified `Worksheet` (or `Range`)

Comment: So the code runs from the workbook holding `rapport` worksheet? Try changing to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rapport").Range("A" & iCnt).Formula = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iCnt).Formula`. Opening the desktop workbook will cause it to become the `ActiveWorkbook` instead of what you thought (the Document workbook) @Grmn

Comment: Thx @RaymondWu that absolutely did it, Thx all :) learned rather some from all of your comments

Answer (score 0):

No worries being new, we all were at some point.

The first part of your code `'source of data` doesn't work as intended. `iRowsCount` is an `Integer` and not an `Array`. To make use of an array, as you seemingly tried to do, you should use

```
Dim iRowsCount(8) As Long
With src.Worksheets("Sheet")
    iRowsCount(1) = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count
    ' ...
End With
' ...
```

If you use an Integer only the last row will be assigned. So if "AT", for some reason, has 5 rows, `iRowsCount` will be 5. Nothing else. Not accounting for "AQ" or "AS".

But in your case, Integer/Long would probably suffice *if* all rows have the exact same count. One assignment would be enough then.

Regarding `.Formula` - are you really trying to write formulas? Have you tried `.value` instead?

And, *what may be the crux of the matter*, try `Worksheets("rapport").Save` or `Worksheets("rapport").SaveAs` at the end of your function.

(Haven't tested it on my end so far.)

**Additionally**, please remember to set `Exit Sub` (or `Exit Function` respectively, if a `Function`) to avoid executing `ErrHandler` if no error occurs.

*(Sorry, I'm new to Stackoverflow, so I can't write comments as of yet.)*

(Edit: Thanks for the reminder, @FunThomas, Integer is only -32768 to 32767. Long is 8 bytes.)

Comment: Tried .Formula > .Value and added .Save however no copy of columns

Comment: Never use Integer, use Long! Escpecially true when it comes to row number in Excel.

Comment: Changed Integer to Long, same result :(

Comment: Thanks for the info, @FunThomas! / Too bad, @Grmn, I was hoping ".Save" works.

Comment: In this case the error handler code is meant to be run even when there is no error. `Exit Sub` is not applicable .